# Preenchimento randomico de matriz com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web

Estou tentando criar um mapa com terra e agua em javascript mas quero que seja completamente aleatório, para isso atribuí 0's e 1's em uma matriz e onde tinha 0 coloquei o chão e onde tinha 1 coloquei agua. Agora eu queria saber como preencher essa matriz com 0 e 1 "randomicamente" para que cada vez que eu dê f5 aparecer uma coisa diferente e maluca.

Segue abaixo o código que eu estou usando:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Canvas Tile Map</title>

    <style>
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 360px;
            margin top: -25px;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mapa randômico</h1>

    <canvas id="canvas" height="400px" width="480px"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var mapArray = [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ];

        var grama = new Image();
        var agua = new Image();

        grama.src = 'grama.png';
        agua.src = 'agua.png';

        var posX = 0;
        var posY = 0;

        //verifica elementos do vetor e atribui uma tile
        grama.onload = function() {
            agua.onload = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {

                    for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {

                        if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
                            context.drawImage(grama, posX, posY, 40, 40);
                        }

                        if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
                            context.drawImage(agua, posX, posY, 40, 40);
                        }

                        posX += 40;

                    }

                    posY += 40;
                    posX = 0;

                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    </br>
    <button>gerar arquivo</button>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se percebo bem queres gerar uma matrix `10 x 12` com `0`s e `1`s.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
function gerarMatriz(x, y) {
  /* ou se preferires mais estático tira os argumentos e faz:
  var x = 10;
  var y = 12;
  */
  var matriz = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var linha = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      linha.push(Math.round(Math.random()));
    }
    matriz.push(linha);
  }
  return matriz;
}
setInterval(function() {
  var matriz = gerarMatriz(10, 12);
  document.body.innerHTML = matriz.map(l => '<br>' + l);
}, 500);
```